# How to stop sliding in Slidingmenu Android

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingmenu

I'm using [Jfeinstein10's sliding menu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/) in my app as follows:

```
slidingMenu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        slidingMenu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        slidingMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        slidingMenu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_shadow_width);
        slidingMenu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.slidingmenu_shadow);
        slidingMenu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        slidingMenu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        slidingMenu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        slidingMenu.setMenu(R.layout.slidingmenu);
```

I also activated a menu key listener:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {
            this.slidingMenu.toggle();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Now, I want this menu to pop up ONLY when menu key is pressed, and not when swiping from left. I want to do this because I have horizontal scrolling in my activity and this conflicts with the sliding menu.

How do I disable the sliding part and keep only the menu button activation part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. This was actually easy to solve.

I changed the line

```
slidingMenu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
```

to

```
slidingMenu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_MARGIN);
```

And then changed the MARGIN value in the library to 0.0 dp.

Hope that helps someone!